# How to add a straight line to ScatterChart?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to add a straight line in a ui.Chart of ScatterChart type but I didn't find any reference in the docs. The closest I've found is the **trendlines** option, but this is not what I really need. Trendlines draws a linear regression, but I need a ([0,0],[1,1]) line, just like an abline in R.

In the picture below, the green line is what I've got with trendlines, but I need to add the black line to the plot.

[image]